# why is there a huge difference existed in model performance score obtained from 10-fold cross validation?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

I'm using **gradient boosting regression model** (GBRT).

To evaluate this model, I use **10-fold cross validation**, in each of which I set **same parameters** , thus **The only difference btw folds is just the training&test dataset**.

For each fold, I compute the **coefficient of determination as a measure of fitting**.

However, I find that there exists a huge difference in coefficient of determination obtained from each fold, e.g., the coefficient of determination from fold_1 to fold_10 is:

[ 0.95310245  0.89725342  0.886711    **0.97063794**  0.84182142  0.80870443
  0.70535911  0.8888032   **0.42510782**  0.70421155]

**Although the mean is 0.81 and std is 0.31, there is a fold in which the coefficient of determination is 0.4, while another fold is 0.97.**

, why does there exist such huge difference? Is such difference indicating that the performance of my model is not good?

Comment: How do you apply the cross-valiation? The data is not shuffled by default (iirc) which might lead to large variations between folds. Also, your data could just be small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this means you have over-fitting problem, try choosing different parameters set. You can learn more about parameters search in 'Parameter estimation using grid search with cross-validation' scikit-learn example http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/grid_search_digits.html